# How to make a collectionView with resizable cells horizontally in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I want to create a collection view that has different sized cells. My final outcome is something like this picture

[image: picture].

Comment: I think you need to Use any **Tag List view** Third-party library for above Output.

Answer (score 0):

Your class needs to also implement the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` protocol. Initialize the collection view like so:

```
let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
collectionView.delegate = self
```

And then you can implement the function `sizeForItemAt`:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let width = // get the width
        let height = // get the height
        return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
    }
```

As long as your screen can fit multiple of your widths, the collection view will automatically fit them horizontally.